# Vue.js scroll to top of new page route after setTimeout

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a page transition that doesn't work nicely when the scroll to the top of a new route is instant. I'd like to wait 100ms before it automatically scrolls to the top. The following code doesn't end up scrolling at all. Is there a way to do this?

```
export default new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'Home',
            component: Home
        }
    ],
    scrollBehavior (to, from, savedPosition) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            return { x: 0, y: 0 }
        }, 100);
    }
})
```

Comment: Could you mark an answer pls...

Answer (score 64):

This is natively supported by **Vue** now, use `scrollBehaviour`, like this:

```
export default new Router({
  scrollBehavior() {
    return { x: 0, y: 0 };
  },
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Home',
      component: Home
    }
  ],
  mode: 'history'
});
```

[More here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/scroll-behavior.html).

Comment: This works and is native to Vue Router, should be the definitive answer.

Comment: is it possible to add smooth scroll ?

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question. It should not have the most upvotes. @EdwinDonaldo had the correct answer. (in the quickest amount of time)

Answer (score 25):

The other answers fail to handle edge cases such as:

1. [Saved
   Position](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/scroll-behavior.html) - The saved position occurs when the user clicks the back or forward positions. We want to maintain the location the user was looking at.
2. [Hash Links](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/scroll-behavior.html) - E.g. `http://example.com/foo#bar` should navigate to the element on the page with an `id` of `bar`.
3. Finally, in all other cases we can navigate to the top of the page.

Here is the sample code that handles all of the above:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes,
  scrollBehavior: (to, from, savedPosition) => {
    if (savedPosition) {
      return savedPosition;
    } else if (to.hash) {
      return {
        selector: to.hash
      };
    } else {
      return { x: 0, y: 0 };
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: "We want to maintain the location the user was looking at." - This is bad UX. Users are used to being shown the top of the page, there could be specific cases for this, but this isn't normal to do.
I don't understand why you're talking about hash links, this is not related to the initial question.

Comment: This is good UX when we are talking about the back button. The user is taken back to the screen as they last saw it. If we jumped to the top of the page when the user hit back, they would be momentarily disoriented.
Most people will copy/paste code, I think it's helpful to provide small extra details, as long as it doesn't detract from the main answer.

Comment: @EdgarQuintero when you are on a "list page" and drilling down to the details and then going back it's very annoying if application always returns to the top especially when the list is long and you are trying to find some specific item by its content. I personally found myself in such situations quite a few times and at that point I hated the developer who implemented that UX. Might be a subject to a specific use case but you can't refer to "maintaining the location the user was looking at" as a bad UX. At least not in general case.

Comment: Correct, there are certainly use cases for that, I meant it as a default. Navigating between routes on main page views and not scrolling up be default is not right.

Comment: It doesn't scroll up on navigation.

Answer (score 12):

If you want this to happen on every route, you can do so in the before [hook](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html) in the router:

```
const router = new VueRouter({ ... })

router.beforeEach(function (to, from, next) { 
    setTimeout(() => {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }, 100);
    next();
});
```

If you are on an older version of vue-router, use:

```
router.beforeEach(function (transition) { 
    setTimeout(() => {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }, 100);
    transition.next();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to wait a long time use Async Scrolling of `scrollBehaviour`, like this:

```
export default new Router({
  scrollBehavior() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve({ x: 0, y: 0 })
      }, 100)
    })
  },
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Home',
      component: Home
    }
  ],
  mode: 'history'
});
```

[More here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/scroll-behavior.html#async-scrolling).

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the best way, but adding

`document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;`

in a route's core component's (in this case, `Home`) `mounted()` function achieves what I want.

Comment: Unnecessary, this is natively supported by Vue.

Answer (score 0):

When using client-side routing, we may want to scroll to top when navigating to a new route, or preserve the scrolling position of history entries just like real page reload does. vue-router allows you to achieve these and even better, allows you to completely customize the scroll behavior on route navigation.

**Note: this feature only works if the browser supports** `history.pushState`.

```
scrollBehavior (to, from, savedPosition) {
  return { x: 0, y: 0 }
}
```

**With Saved Position:**

```
scrollBehavior (to, from, savedPosition) {
  if (savedPosition) {
    return savedPosition
  } else {
    return { x: 0, y: 0 }
  }
}
```

[For more information](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/scroll-behavior.html#scroll-behavior)

Comment: For more info https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/scroll-behavior.html#scroll-behavior

Answer (score 0):

It is as simple as this code:

```
const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
        return { top: 0 } // always scroll to top
    },
    routes,
});
```