# position scrollY no changed when route change - vuejs

Tags: vue.js, scroll, nuxt.js

When I clicked to set size of product in div of class '`select__item`',my route: `this.$router.push({ query: { ...this.$route.query, size: value } })` ,no refresh page, only url change and scroll back to top. I want position scrollY no changed when I click set size for product. Thank you for help me .Here is my code:

> Product.vue

```
<Product>
<!--some component-->
    <Sizes>
    </Sizes>

</Product>
```

> Sizes.vue

```
<Sizes>
            <div class="select__items no-scrollbar">
                <div
                    v-for="size in product.sizes"
                    :key="size.id"
                    :class="['select__item', { active: size.id == currentSizeId }]"
                    :title="size.name"
                >
                    <button class="select__label" @click="currentSizeId = size.id">
                        {{ size.name }}
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
</Sizes>
```

> computed

```
computed: {

    currentSize() {
        return this.product.sizes.find((s) => s.id == this.currentSizeId)
    },
    currentSizeId: {
        get() {
            this.$nuxt.$emit('setsize', this.$route.query.size)
            return this.$route.query.size
        },
        set(value) {
            if (this.currentSizeId == value) {
                return
            }
            this.$router.push({ query: { ...this.$route.query, size: value } })
        },
    },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Default case in VueJs is to keep Yscroll position when changing page.

You can change your vue-router setting to scroll to the top of your page each time you changing it;

There is a StackOverflow here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50901500/12592396

And a more compete answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52111880/12592396

The short anwser is to define scrollBehavior on your Router:

```
export default new Router({
    mode: ...,
    routes: [
        ...
    ],
    scrollBehavior (to, from, savedPosition) {
        return { x: 0, y: 0 }
    }
})
```